# Ember 2.16 Error when creating a state hash in routes/application

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

Im new to ember coming from react. Inside the routes/application.js I want to use a "state" hash to hold variables outside supporting functions, model(), and actions().

Here is what works:

```
  session: Ember.inject.service(),
  servers: null,
  clients: null,
  variable3: null,
  variable4: null,
  variable3_id: null,
  selectedDate: null,
  currentUser: Ember.inject.service(),
```

and this is what I want to do:

```
state: {
    session: Ember.inject.service(),
    servers: null,
    clients: null,
    variable3: null,
    variable4: null,
    variable3_id: null,
    selectedDate: null,
    currentUser: Ember.inject.service(),
},
```

When I access it with, say get, `get(this, 'state.session')` I get this error:

`ember.debug.js:29034 Error while processing route: analytics Assertion Failed: Attempting to lookup an injected property on an object without a container, ensure that the object was instantiated via a container. Error: Assertion Failed: Attempting to lookup an injected property on an object without a container, ensure that the object was instantiated via a container.`

When I dont put the variables in my `state` hash, and access with get, `get(this, 'session')` I dont get any issues. What is going on here? Did I provide enough info or am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to ember.js.

As mentioned in the error message, `state` is not created by ember container hence ember cannot inject a service to it. Controllers, services, routes, components, instance-initializers are created by ember, but not plain objects.

Use a component or a controller to hold `state`. You don't need to use a separate state object. The `component`s properties are its state actually.

On the other hand, any `service` (which is mostly singleton) shouldn't be the state of something.

Last, of course there are ways to add those `service`s to that `state` object. But this is not the common usage.

Comment: Thanks for your welcoming @ykaragol!

Comment: A better word to use would be _props for route properties instead of state. I looked into services, and it looks like the best course for me is to accept a long list of properties before route methods.